# ActionScript 3.0 Drag and Drop single object to multiple targets until all target filled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to drag and drop a movieclip to 5 targets (movieclips)
normal drag and drop are working fine with its targets, but now i am trying to drop a single movieclip multiple times to 5 targets until all the target are filled.

Please help me

Comment: [so] is not a site to do your work for you. Show some research effort. Just stating what you want is not a question.

Comment: http://www.senocular.com/flash/source/?entry=726 Senocular has some source code you can download which will get you halfway there. You'll just need to add a conditional type code for this to stop working when all 5 are filled.